# Integrate Hangfire Dashboard With ASP.NET Application based Login

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, basic-authentication, dashboard, hangfire

My **`ASP.NET`** project uses a login screen which allows the users to enter credentials in order to sign in to the web application. At that point, the User object is set in the Session object. The User object contains information about the role of the user logged in. Now, I want the **`hangfire`** dashboard to be a link inside the application visible once the user logs in. And upon clicking the link, based on if the user's role is appropriate, I want to show or restrict the dashboard. How do I do this? I am not able to access the session object in the OWIN `startup.cs` class.

Comment: Using session state is a horrible approach. Avoid it

Comment: Any pointers to how it should be handled then?

Comment: what's your membership and role provider?

Answer (score 2):

You can restrict access to the dashboard using an IAuthorizationFilter defined like this:

```
public class DashboardAuthorizationFilter : IAuthorizationFilter
{
    public bool Authorize(IDictionary<string, object> owinEnvironment)
    {
        // In case you need an OWIN context, use the next line,
        // `OwinContext` class is the part of the `Microsoft.Owin` package.
        //var context = new OwinContext(owinEnvironment);
        var ok = false;
        if (HttpContext.Current != null && HttpContext.Current.User != null)
        {
            ok = IsAuthorizedForDashboard(HttpContext.Current.User);
        }
        return ok;
    }
}
```

Where `IsAuthorizedForDashboard` is a function you will need to create.

Then register the filter like this:

```
app.UseHangfireDashboard(DashboardPath, 
    new DashboardOptions { 
        AuthorizationFilters = new List<IAuthorizationFilter> { 
            new DashboardAuthorizationFilter() } 
    });
```